# Putting html code into an template

Tags: html, css

I want to create a table, with a certain fixed number of columns and rows.  I will be using this exact table several times so I want to make it into a template.  Then just call the template instead of copy-and-pasting the code block.

Is this possible?  Any better solutions?
Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need some server-side scripting to do that. ;) Is that ok? If so, what languages can you and would you like to use?

Comment: uhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.   There are lots of ways to approach this, you could use a javascript or server side solution.  You need to be more specific about what you mean about using it in many different places.

Comment: @Pikrass Yes that's fine.  For my back-end I was planning on using php.

Comment: If you're using PHP you can use [`include`](http://au1.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

Comment: @Rooster By different places I meant using the object/html code block as a regular html tag.  This way to save space and organization.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [mustache templating](http://mustache.github.io/) with javascript. [ICanHaz.jz](http://icanhazjs.com/) makes mustache templating on the client side fairly easy too.

**EDIT:** As your comment specifies that you will be using PHP now, I would still suggest mustache templating, but you could [implement it using PHP](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php) instead.

Comment: I don't really like these Javascript-based solutions. All clients don't support Javascript (e.g. Braille devices), and that would make the site completely unusable with them. The same thing applies to web crawlers. OP can use server-side scripting so he should use that. If he couldn't, he could have used some Bash/Perl/Ruby/... scripts to generate the HTML and put that on the server.

Comment: He didn't specify what the solution is for. Based solely on his question, he may not even be using server side code (could just be a learning project). Mustache templating is available in PHP.

Comment: Using a template engine in a language that is already basically a template engine is quite redundant. :)

Comment: Pikrass no mention was made of supporting braille devices or Internet Explorer 3, so I'm sure javascript support isn't an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "code block" you mean you can reuse the template just by saying <my_cool_custom_table></my_cool_custom_table>, I'm afraid it's not really "possible", at least not client-side.

You may want to read up on [shadow dom](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/), as this is exactly what things like input, video, textarea and other elements use to encapsulate complex structures into one element. However, it's not standardized.

Answer (score 0):

So in any case, you'll need to learn a script language, if you don't know one already. You mentioned PHP, so I'll demonstrate with that.

Note that I'm using really basic programming skills here. You want to learn to make more sophisticated code, or maybe learn a framework, if you plan to create a complex website.

In one HTML file, let call it `table.html`, you'll have your table, and only that. Then in every page where you need it you include that file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><!-- ... --></head>
    <body>
        The table:
        <?php include 'table.html'; ?>
        Tada! You can include it more than once:
        <?php include 'table.html'; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

You need to tell your web server to interpret these files as PHP. To do that, most of the time you just need to install the Apache PHP5 module (it's already installed if you have a mutualized hosting) and be sure to name your files with the `.php` extension.